# Manipulating data- with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
document.getElementById('divw').data-value=james;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loading-bar.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loading-bar.js"></script>


<div id="divw" class="ldBar" data-type="fill" data-img="https://www.mediumpath.com/images/logo.png"></div>
```

Above is my code, and I want to add `data-value` attribute into element with id `divw` but it seems do not the attribute with value, please tell me what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must to use `setAttribute("data-value",james)`, because JavaScript syntax doesn't allow `-` in identifier names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

> Sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

Please Note: since `james` is a string, you have to wrap that with quotes.

Use `setAttribute()` in the following way:

```js
document.getElementById('divw').setAttribute('data-value', 'james');

// check the new value with getAttribute()
console.log(document.getElementById('divw').getAttribute('data-value'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loading-bar.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loading-bar.js"></script>


<div id="divw" class="ldBar" data-type="fill" data-img="https://www.mediumpath.com/images/logo.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For most attributes `.setAttribute()` would be a good way to read and manipulate them, but data attributes are slightly special. In addition to using `.setAttribute()`, You can also use the dataset property to [access data- attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('divw');

divw.dataset.value = "blah";
```

Note that when using dataset, you'd need to remove the `data-` prefix and convert the rest of the name from `kebab-case` to `camelCase`.